# Append/Pre-append text in Laravel Form selectRange

Tags: laravel

When generating a `selectRange` in Laravel, is it possible to append or pre-append text to the select options label? Like a `%` sign for instance, so all the labels will read `{number}%`.

```
{!! Form::selectRange('number', 1, 99) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing in Laravel Collective core. I have created my own utility class which extends from Laravel Collective form builder.

In your blade, you can simply write:

```
{!! MyCustomForm::selectRange('number', 1, 99, ' %') !!}
```

---

This is my custom class which extends from Laravel Collectives Form builder:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Utilities;

use Collective\Html\FormFacade;

class MyCustomForm extends FormFacade
{
    /**
     * Create a select range field with appending text.
     * This function overrides Laravel Collective Form::selectRange()
     * function.
     *
     * @param   string  $name
     * @param   string  $begin
     * @param   string  $end
     * @param   string  $appended_text
     * @param   string  $selected
     * @param   array   $options
     * @return  string
     */
    public static function selectRange($name, $begin, $end, $appended_text = null, $selected = null, $options = array()){
        $html = parent::selectRange($name, $begin, $end, $selected, $options);

        $dom = new \DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($html);
        $xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);
        $options = $xpath->query("*/select[@name='" . $name . "']/option");

        foreach ($options as $option) {
            $option->nodeValue = $option->nodeValue . $appended_text;
        }

        $html = self::innerHTML($dom->documentElement->firstChild);
        return $html;
    }

    /**
     * This function removes HTML DOCTYPE, html tag and body tag from the
     * generated DOM HTML.
     *
     * @param  DOMNode  $node
     * @return string
     */
    public static function innerHTML($node){
        $doc = new \DOMDocument();
        foreach ($node->childNodes as $child)
            $doc->appendChild($doc->importNode($child, true));

        return $doc->saveHTML();
    }
}
```

Let me know if there is still something vague.